# Flexbox, with minimum CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I would like to implement a cards container using Flexbox. I have some already developed solutions, but I want to be sure I am using the most modern and minimalistic configuration. I have this one below available in fiddle. What is missing, important to me, is to have the DIV with a 100% width when it is the only one in the row (so mobile..):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-container div {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 2mm;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 80px;
  background-color: #26f;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do with a Flex configuration or should I use media queries?

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap? Is that what you're using?

Comment: Of course this should be handled via media queries, don’t see how that’s even a question ...

Comment: Neither Flexbox nor media query can detect whether there is a single element in the last row, for that you need script. What you can do though, is to define break points where you _know_ there is one, and for that you use media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use flex-grow in the child DIVs...

```
.flex-container div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-container div {
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 2mm;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 80px;
  background-color: #26f;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```